# How to suppress sensitive log information in ASP.NET Core which is using Log4Net for logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, log4net

I have an application which is based on ASP.NET Core and i am using Log4Net as a logging provider.

I have a requirement, where I should be able to either **suppress** the sensitive information from being logged or by **anonymizing** that sensitive information.

I need to be able to configure the keywords so that those details are suppressed before writing to the log file.

Is there any Library/NuGet package available which I can use along with Log4Net to achieve the required functionality or any other solution?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's your log statements. What prevents you from not logging what you don't want logged? (based on keywords, or otherwise)

Comment: You can refer [this](https://github.com/amigup/ApplicationInsights.Extension.RequestLogging) as reference for concept